# Recurrent equation with UnitStep function using RSolve

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I have the following equation to solve
$$a[n+1] = a[n] + 6 - 100\cdot \theta(a[n]-100)$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. So I tried the following

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 6 - 100*UnitStep[a[n] - 100], a[0] == 0}, a[n], n]
```

and it did not work.

Is there a way to solve a recurrent equation with step function in Mathematica?

I use 13.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Using a different approach than using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a[0] = 0;

a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + 6 - 100*UnitStep[a[n - 1] - 100]
```

After the initial `0`, each block of 50 values are identical sets of three runs

```
seq = a /@ Range[100];

blocks = Partition[Split[seq, #2 > #1 &], 3]

(* {{{6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96, 102}, {8, 
   14, 20, 26, 32, 38, 44, 50, 56, 62, 68, 74, 80, 86, 92, 98, 104}, {10, 16, 
   22, 28, 34, 40, 46, 52, 58, 64, 70, 76, 82, 88, 94, 100}}, {{6, 12, 18, 24,
    30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96, 102}, {8, 14, 20, 26, 32, 
   38, 44, 50, 56, 62, 68, 74, 80, 86, 92, 98, 104}, {10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 40, 
   46, 52, 58, 64, 70, 76, 82, 88, 94, 100}}} *)

SameQ @@ blocks

(* True *)
```

The Length of the three runs are

```
Length /@ blocks[[1]]

(* {17, 17, 16} *)
```

The sequences are

```
FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & /@ blocks[[1]]

(* {6 n, 2 (1 + 3 n), 2 (2 + 3 n)} *)
```

The definition of `a` is then

```
Clear[a]

a[0] = 0;

a[m_Integer?Positive] = Module[{n = Mod[m - 1, 50] + 1},
  Piecewise[{
     {6 n, n < 18},
     {2 (1 + 3 (n - 17)), n < 35},
     {2 (2 + 3 (n - 34)), n < 51}}] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
(a /@ Range[50]) === (a /@ Range[51, 100]) ===
 (a /@ Range[101, 150]) === Flatten[blocks[[1]]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly solves the given equation. But I am wondering, are there some more general ways to do it? Because the next step I had in mind is to solve a system of coupled equations like:

a[n + 1] == a[n] + 6*b[n] - 100*UnitStep[a[n] - 100] and 
b[n + 1] == b[n] + UnitStep[a[n] - 100].

I've tried to modify your solution by defining bunction b[n_] := b[n] =b[n-1]+ UnitStep[a[n - 1] - 100], but, apparently, it does not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with a recursive solution:

```
a[0] = 0;
a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + 6 - 100*UnitStep[a[n - 1] - 100];
ListPlot[Table[a[i], {i, 50}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It does not look like a right solution. I suppose, the solution should follow sawtooth pattern.

[Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28n+%2B+1%29+%3D%3D+a%28n%29+%2B+6+-+100*UnitStep%28a%28n%29+-+100%29%2C+a%280%29%3D0)

Comment: Sorry, I over looked the a[n] in the UnitStep. IIt is fixed now.

Comment: I suppose, you meant sol[n_]:= If[6*n<100,6 n, -2 (-800 + 47 n)]]. But still, the solution is correct for n<=16, but than goes down forever instead of sawtooth.

Comment: I think a recursive solution is simpler. I changed my answer.